# Probability a group is unrepresented

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

> 11 students from each of Engineering, Science, Humanities, and Social Science were nominated to represent their faculties. 7 of these 44 students will be randomly chosen to be on the student council. What is the probability that at least one of the four faculties will be unrepresented on the student council?

I tried to answer this question by counting the total number of ways we can pick a student council leaving one of the faculties out, which is $33C7$ + $33C7$ + $33C7$ + $33C7$ for each faculty being left out, and then divided this by the total amount of possible student councils: $44C7$. This answer, however, is incorrect, and I'm not sure what the error is.

Comment: Does "under-represented" mean even one person less than given by probability?  Just *one*??

Comment: It's "un"-represented, so none from the given faculty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the groups $A,B,C,D$
Regardless of whether other groups are represented or not,

P($1$ particular group  unrepresented) $= \Large\frac{\binom{33}{7}}{\binom{44}{7}}= x\;(say)$

P($2$ particular groups  unrepresented) $= \Large\frac{\binom{22}{7}}{\binom{44}{7}}= y\;(say)$

P($3$ particular groups  unrepresented) $= \Large\frac{\binom{11}{7}}{\binom{44}{7}}= z\;(say)$

Then, by the [principle of inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)

P(at least one group unrepresented)

$= 1 - \binom41x + \binom42y - \binom43z$

Answer (score 0):

You have over-counted several cases, for example if the council is 7 engineers, this appears in 3 of your options.

The probability that ay least one from each faculty is chosen is the probability that some combination of 4111, 3211 or 2221 is chosen, so 1- this answer gives the answer to the question.